# Ember. Using built-in views inside your own view

Tags: javascript, ember.js, view

I have a model which contains information about selects, inputs and etc. I found the way to connect it to my view.

```
export default Em.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    var content = this.get('content'),
    self = this;
    content.content[0].default.forEach(function(item,i){
      if (item.tag == 'select') {
        self.$().append('<select></select>');
        item.content.forEach(function(item){
          self.$('select:last-child').append('<option>'+item.option+'</option>');
        });
      }
      else if (item.tag == 'input') {
        self.$().append('<input type='+item.type+'>');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Is there a way to not use:

```
self.$('select:last-child').append('<option>'+item.option+'</option>');
```

And have some kind of

```
Ember.compile('{{Ember.select content=options valueBinding=example}}');
```

Thanks!

P.S. Sorry if you find my way to do it to be silly, i just started to learn Ember and may be I still think in jquery's way. And sorry for my English!

Comment: What is the actual purpose of the view? What functionality does it offer on the surface? And yes, your code is overly dependent on jQuery.

Comment: The taks is to build form from the JSON file, where parts of the form can be changed, deleted just editing JSON.

Comment: Just add a `isSelect`and `isInput` to the item and use normal if helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is:

```
{{#each item in defaultArray}}
    {{#if item.isSelect}}
    {{view "select" content=item.content optionLabelPath="content.option" prompt=""}}
    {{/if}}
    {{#if item.isRadio}}
    {{item.label}}
    {{#each item in item.content}}
     <input type="checkbox" class="radio" {{bind-attr name="item.name" id="item.id" value="item.option"}}>
     <label {{bind-attr for="item.id"}}>{{item.option}}</label>
    {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```